# modalViewController issue with UITextField first responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikeyboard

I have a UIViewController called LoginViewController. The UIViewController has two UITextField, username and password. This is displayed as a modalViewController when the first time the app is launched and there isn't any credentials in the keychain. When the user clicks on the login button the keyboard that is presented is dismissed. The code is:

```
- (IBAction) loginClick: (UIButton *) sender
{
    if ([username isFirstResponder]){
        [username resignFirstResponder];
    }

    if ([password isFirstResponder]){
        [password resignFirstResponder];
    }

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.username = username.text;
    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.password = password.text;
    [progressLock lock]; 
    [progressLock unlockWithCondition:0];
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/account/verify.json" objectClass:[Login class] delegate: self];
}
```

Now inside the app there is an options button. When this is click it will present a modalViewController which has a logout button in it. Clicking on this logout button will present the LoginViewController again. The code is:

```
- (IBAction) logout:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * username = [standardDefaults stringForKey:@"kApplicationUserNameKey"]; 
    NSError * error = nil;

    [standardDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"kApplicationUserNameKey"];
    [SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:username andServiceName:@"convore" error:&error];
    LoginViewController* lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    lvc.delegate = self;
    [self.mgvc.groups removeAllObjects];
    [self.mgvc.table reloadData];

    Topic * topic = [Topic object];
    topic.tid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-2];
    self.mgvc.detailViewController.topic = topic;
    self.mgvc.detailViewController.detailItem = topic.tid;

    [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
    [lvc release];  
}
```

What's weird is that I can't seem to dismiss the keyboard when I click on the login button this time. Why is this? Is it because as of now I am displaying the LoginViewController from a modalviewcontroller? How do I solve this weird issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether the fact that you can't dismiss the keyboard is due to presenting the login in a modal view, nor do I see anything evidently wrong with your code.

I would suggest you to change your flow and make:

1. the logout button dismiss your first modal view and,
2. your login view be displayed as a normal view, once the modal view disappears.

Explicitly, you can do 2 either by one of several means:

1. trying and pushing the login view controller on your navigation controller (if you have one);
2. selecting it in a tab bar controller (if you use one);
3. your modal view is shown above a view; when the modal is dismissed, that view appears again, and so the `viewWillAppear` selector of its view controller is called; that's the place where you can check if you are logged in or out and show the login, if necessary; if you don't know how to detect if your are in or out, you can always set a flag in the view controller when you dismiss the logout modal view.

   1. (after reading your comment: modal view is not full screen, so `viewWillAppear` is not called: you can either send `viewWillAppear` yourself, or send a different, custom message to your superordinate view controller so that it knows that the login view should be displayed (and possibly refresh the view).
   2. EDIT: try something like this (this requires that you call your own selector, not `viewWillAppear`):

      `[baseNonModalViewController performSelector:@selector(yourSelector) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];`

Executing `performSelector` with a 0.0 delay, has only the effect of scheduling `yourSelector` for execution on the main loop. This way, first the modal will be completely dismissed, then the login view will be displayed.

Comment: that's a good idea, so you mean doing  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES]; ?? I tried that and it didn't work.. maybe this is not the way it should be

Comment: You should try and do that from outside the modal view to make a difference. See my edit, specifically the option 3 I added.

Comment: how can I do this from the outside? a delegate you mean?

Comment: option 3: you modal view is shown above a view; when the modal is dismissed, that view appears, and so the `viewWillAppear` selector of the view controller is called; that's the place where you can check if you are in or out and show the login, if necessary.

Comment: I think I can only go with option 3... so I have to share a logout status from a delegate?

Comment: yeah, a delegate is a very clean solution. or you can set a flag in the view controller when the logout is done. (less clean)

Comment: one issue is that the viewWillAppear is not triggered when the modalView is dismissed as the type of the modalView is not a full screen one, instead it's a form sheet.. (this is an ipad app)

Comment: you can trigger it yourself, this should be no problem... anyway, see my suggestion 4 (writing it now)

Comment: I tried doing  LoginViewController* lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        lvc.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
        [lvc release];
from the view behind the modalViewController and for some weird reason it doesn't show any modalViewController. I tried for other view, not just LoginViewController and it didn't show up